# What is the optimal stack for building on Yodlee

Tags: java, ruby, playframework, yodlee

I would like to build a web application that heavily relies on the Yodlee SDK. I have quite a bit of familiarity with front end dev, and low level assembly and then Java. However, I'm also okay learning something like Node or ROR if it proves most condusive.

I hope this does not appear too subjective, but I was wondering what would be the best way to tackle this decision. .NET or Java seem to be the optimal way to handle the Yodlee integration. Should I stick with a Java based framework such as the Play! framework, or should I work off of a more well documented/adopted framework like Ruby on Rails and rely on Yodlee's SOAP API and use something like Savon (http://savonrb.com/?

I would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Did you end up getting a Savon client working?  I'm starting on the same process right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get the best answers asking these questions in the Developer Forum at forum.yodlee.com - but I'll answer here for you.

The SOAP interface is fully compliant, so any language will work.  If you have an expertise in any language - you should use that language.  There have been Java, .NET, PHP, Ruby, Perl and [JavaScript (Node)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yodlee) integrations.  So anything will work.

If you are truly language agnostic - I would recommend Java using Apache Axis.  Here are some comments:

Yodlee offers sample code in both Java and C#.  So if you want to be able to get good examples in you native language and even have some copy-paste code reuse from the platform when choosing either Java or C# will be the most helpful.

The Yodlee Platform runs Java on the server side and you will notice the SOAP API that there are some simulated classes like "java.util.Date" which will get fully mapped to a Date object in Java, but be a value-object in other languages unless you create type-mappers.  So if you are truly technology agnostic, than I would suggest Java as the most natural language to build a client applications in.

Hope this is helpful,
Jordan Reed, Yodlee Product Management

Comment: is there an NPM module for Node, and/or some JavaScript samples you could point us at?